# Rewrite in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page locally that is /shop but I want it to redirect to /shop/designs

I tried to do it with .htaccess but nothing seems to be working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/shop/.*$ /shop/designs/ [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, but in `htaccess`, you cannot use `/` at the beginning of the path regex.

Change your rule like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop$ shop/designs [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's not working either.

This is my .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop$ shop/designs [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Sorry, can't put that in a codeblock.

Comment: @zx81 answer should work. Anyway, if you have an trailing slash after shop you should modify the second line as follows:

RewriteRule ^shop\/?$ /shop/designs [R=301,L]